# Google Apps Script - Calling custom function from a custom menu - Not nested

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is where I am at currently:

```
function sendEmails() {
  //Function to send Emails
}

function onOpen() {
  // Funtion 1 to add custom menu
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Reminder', 'menuItem1')
      .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
  // Funtion 2 to add custom menu
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  sheet.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
     .sendEmails()
     .alert('Reminder Emails Sent!');
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getUi in object Sheet

The primary way I call the sendEmails() function is by scheduling it.
I couldn't find a way to call this function manually via the menu.

Could you please help me out with this?

Comment: Like the error says, there's no function called getUi in sheet object. It's in spreadsheet object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess we dont need to call sendEmails within UI, we can directly call it on menu item select.

Something like this:

```
function sendEmails() {
  //Function to send Emails
}

function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        .createMenu('Custom Menu')
            .addItem('Send Reminders', 'sendEmails')
            .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked.

It was just a little syntax error then. I am used to always adding () at the end of functions.

Answer (score 1):

**Sending Emails onOpen()**

This requires you to create an onOpen trigger for for `myonOpen` and it will display a dialog that says `sending emails`.  After sendEmails() completes it returns message sent to the dialog and it is displayed on the dialog.  Or you could add google.script.host.close() to the withSuccessHandler and it would just close the dialog.

```
function sendEmails() {
  return 'Emails Sent';//have send emails return a message
}

//You have to create an installable onOpen for this
function myonOpen() {
  runDlg();

}

function runDlg() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var html='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
  html+='<body><h1>"Sending Emails"</h1></body>';
  html+='<script>$(function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(msg){$("body").append(msg);}).sendEmails();});console.log("My Code");</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Data');
}
```

Animation:

[image]

Comment: I think @Ishaan just wanted a way to call their custom `sendEmails` function. What you have given is a very nice way communicate between dialog & script. Thank you!

Comment: This not what I asked for but it is really interesting! Wow.

I'm sure I'll be able to use it somewhere in a later project.

Comment: The value of using a dialog like this is that you can issue a command to send emails and when the process is done it can send message back to the call function and that message can be displayed on the dialog.  It could provide additional information about the emailing process like emails that didn't get sent or missing information, etc...